# ASP.net MVC Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried many things but I am facing problem in implementing the following in Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC. Please tell me step by step what should I do to implement the controllers and views. I am confused how to implement many to many relationship between club and manager

#### Manager model

```
public class Manager:Person
{
        public Manager()
        {
            Clubs = new HashSet<Club>();
        }
        public string AssignedDuty { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime AssignedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}
```

#### Club model

```
public class Club
{
    public Club()
    {
        this.Memberships = new HashSet<Membership>();
        this.People = new HashSet<Manager>();
    }

    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }


    public virtual Center Center { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Manager> People { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. I think you should try to split into several questions, or maybe specify it a bit more.

Comment: In order to help you, you could generate the code first model so that you don't have to write this stuff by hand. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx.

Comment: I approached code first model only Now I dont know I am stuck in between, and yes it is broad question I just want to know how to save and retrieve data from a conjuction table that is automatically created with PersonId and ClubId as Clustered Primary key and foreign key

Comment: This is way too broad of a question for SO. I'd recommend you look for a tutorial; that seems more like what you need.

Comment: And also, since you're new here. Don't forget to mark the correct answer and if you find a solution, post it here so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next you create dbContext and connectionstring etc..

Refer below links :

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relationships are defined using a junction table. As for how Controllers are implemented, try this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs

Comment: I know how to create controller but I dont know what should be the code for create and other methods as they are connected through many to many relation

Comment: I want to know how junction table will be used how to store data in it and how to retrieve from it

Answer (score 0):

Your Models as in Model-View-Controller should not be concerned on how the manager is linked to the club in the database. The should just be concerned that they **are** related not **how**.

I would do it like this:

- In your DB/EntityFramework, use a junction table as explained and linked to Juann Strauss
- When you load data from database (as in the OnModelCreating event) you populate the relation

Here is a blog post that seems to explain what you are trying to accomplish: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I read all this and I implemented in the similar way but I am not able to know about how to use that junction table in controller

Answer (score 0):

Finally its working now I only have to add few lines to my controller. and my Final Assign Club looks like this and its working perfectly

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AssignClub")]
public ActionResult AssignClub(AssignClubVM ac)
{
        Manager m = db.Managers.Find(ac.manager.PersonId);
        foreach (var clubid in ac.SelectedClubs)
        {
            m.Clubs.Add(db.Clubs.Find(clubid));
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```